# Which wamp/lamp development environments have openSSL

Tags: php, apache, openssl, wamp

I'm looking for a wamp/lamp development environment that supports OpenSSL out of the box so I can do things with `https://`. I'm not sure if OpenSSL is a feature of Apache or PHP, but I would rather not add that myself. If your development environment supports it, please add it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all of the major ones have got it but the easies and best is WampServer:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/